# How can I store the JSON result from a SOAP Web Service in C#?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, soap, client

I am trying to consume a JSON from a SOAP web service. It has a method `GetData()` which I can call from the browser and there I can see the JSON text

```
{"hasError":false,
"errMessage":null,
"secureResponse":{"WebServiceDt":[{"attr1":"encryptedValue1","attr2":"encryptedValue2"},...]}}
```

In the WSDL there appears the GetDataResponse, but I can't get VisualStudio to recognize it. There's a message saying that I'm missing a reference.

```
wsReference.wsSoapClient client = wsReference.wsSoapClient();
wsReference.GetDataResponse dataResponse = await client.GetDataAsync("encryptedID", "encryptedPassword");
```

Comment: I assume you have added a service reference in the project?

Comment: Yes, I have. So VisualStudio recognizes the methods GetData(), GetDataAsync() but I have no data type to store the result.

Comment: If you use `var` and then hover over the variable what does it show?